What do we deserve?
Aristotle thinks that if we distribute flutes, they should go to the best flute players. It will be the same for all other areas. The fair distribution is made based on the goal, or telos, the end of the thing itself, and therefore, the best flutes should go to the best flute players, because they give honor and recognition to the playing flutes and allows you to achieve this desired end, in the playing of the flute. Who thinks like Aristotle? To know that the best things in life should only go to the best in that field?

It depends on why we're distributing flutes. If the goal is to get the best music now, Aristotle may be right. But if we want to produce more flutists in the future, we should give them to students who will practice with them.

It's a great idea. This is why Aristotle says that it depends on the end of the thing, that for which the thing exists. If indeed it is for good music, yes it should go to the best. I would tell you that even if it is to enter flute players it will in this case come back to the best students, the most talented, those who are on the right path to becoming better flute players, rather than the other students who are less good. This is Aristotle's answer.

That requires the ability to identify them. When grade school students are given a first opportunity to pick an instrument and join the school band, most students' potentials are unknown.

Perhaps to the best unknown flautists. The successful ones will already have a good flute.

Don't you think that if you were a teacher, you wouldn't be able to distinguish who are better than others? Barmar

"if we distribute flutes" - are you giving out free flutes?  Can I have one?  Also "the best flutes" - who decides whhich flutes are the best flutes, and by what criteria?

The student who is best now may not be the student who stays with the instrument longest nor accomplishes the most. I was a good judo student, but fell away from the sport; giving me a a bit of extra attention might have been justified since I was showing signs of being able to teach others, but I certainly had not earned nor did I deserve more than that.

This touches on meritocracy (in fact, the SEP article cites your flute example) and that is a philosophical can of worms that some want to stay far away from.
Your question as to who thinks like Aristotle leaves room for a large number of candidates, especially since the Enlightenment, which introduced the idea of a ruling elite, who would replace the inherited status and wealth of the aristocracy with people who derived their status and power from virtue and talent. Till the last century it was the prevailing thought in the West and it is the ideological basis of the American Dream.
Some modern thinkers that have argued against meritocracy are John Rawls (the 'veil of ignorance' guy) and Robert Nozick, from the right libertarian point of view. But I will not dwell on the Rawls - Nozick debate. Life is too short.
More interesting, I think, are recent discussions on free will which put new emphasis on meritocracy. If we have no free will then how can we blame or praise anyone? Robert Sapolsky recently made a compelling case against meritocracy in his latest book 'Determined'. In an interview he said:

The people who have the most power are the ones who have the most reason to like meritocracies and keep them in place. It’s system justification. We may think that meritocracy makes no sense. But on the other hand, if you have a brain tumor, you’ll want to make sure you’re operated on by a great doctor, not some random person off the street. You need to make sure that competent people are doing the difficult jobs, without telling them that they’re better humans as a result of that, and without having them think that in any way they earned that. The problem with this idea is that it can kill motivation.

And

I think the United States is a particularly strong example of that. Because we have this incredibly strong cultural mythology in the United States, that anybody, if they work hard, can succeed. Anybody can become rich, if they’re motivated enough, any child can grow up to be president. And, you know, in the United States, if you’re born in poverty, there’s about 90% chance that you will still be in poverty as an adult. And every step of the way will explain why that is so. Your neighborhood, your education... However, we have a country where the entire mythology is built on the idea that it is in your power to solve any problem, it only depends on you. Because, look, here’s one person in a million who did it. And we’re going to make it sound like everybody can be there. So at least in the United States, where we have this really poisonous version of meritocracy, it causes an enormous amount of pain.

I think that this is an important subject. Many people think the question of free will is trivial and they will shrug. Who cares? But I think that it is crucial in questions in how we should punish our criminals and how we should reward our heros.

In fact Rawl and Nozick are the liberals. The first is egalitarian liberal and the second is libertarian. Rawls advocates respect for rights, equality of opportunity, he is therefore against meritocracy, I agree. But is Aristotle wrong? if Aristotle is wrong somewhere I just want to know. Why is he wrong? Because it is not a question of being with the latest current of thought, because it is the most recent. If you take sides, you must do so with morally logical reasons, at least from your point of view as a thinking subject.

It's a philosophical debate, no one is right or wrong, we exchange, to know the opinions of others, on questions that concern us all.

@Mass Is Aristotle wrong? I think the problem lies in the telos. With the flutes it seems obvious and it would be hard to disagree with Aristotle. But should we give guns to those who are the most skilled and the most willing to go around shooting people?

Regarding "great doctors", one can point out that, while we should and do of course have some minimal acceptable standard and always aim to be better, we also need plenty of good-but-not-"great" doctors to keep the medical system functioning. If we only have the few "great" doctors, most people won't get medical treatment (... or: even fewer people will get medical treatment). And we also need nurses and other hospital staff, and people to do other not-so-glamorous jobs (even though those people tend to earn mere scraps, and toxic meritocracy may view people in those jobs as "failures").

@Philomath Aristotle would tell you, for what purpose do you use your weapons? I mean, if someone asks me what I use a flute for, the answer won't be to whistle, but rather to produce the best music possible. So for what purpose do we use a weapon?

@NotThatGuy I don't understand what you're thinking?

@Mass The meritocracy argument is that we want "great" doctors, and we want to encourage those people. The counter-argument is not that we don't want great doctors, but that we also want decent doctors, and nurses, and everyone else, so we should balance out encouraging great doctors with encouraging these other things. (And the US' idea of meritocracy likely gives you fewer great doctors compared to possible alternatives, given the large number of people who remain in poverty, as per Sapolsky's subsequent point.)

Well, in one sense most people think this way. If there is a tool designed for a (non-trivial) purpose, then it's common to believe that those best capable of executing the purpose should have use of the tool. Only elite pilots are allowed to fly fighter jets; Amati and Stradivarius violins are reserved for the use of the best violinists; astrophysicists alone get time to use the most powerful telescopes… This is purely functional: anyone can use a 'common' tool, but the 'exquisitely designed' tool is a rarity whose use is generally reserved for those who are proficient. No one believes such tools are to be wasted on dilettantes, wannabes, or the idly curious.
However — modern society being what it is — ownership of exquisite tools is reserved for those who can afford the privilege. Anyone can own an Amati or a Stradivarius (or the James Webb telescope, for the matter) if they can pay the costs. But even though they may own such a thing, they are not (usually) qualified to use it. Most people who pay for such devices acquire them as mere status symbols, and then give, loan, or rent them to those who can make use of their full potential.
Don't conflate the 'best things' with the 'best tools'. In every society (and I'm sure Aristotle would agree) non-productive things go to those who can afford them. If you go to your favorite golf course odds are the best sets of clubs will be owned by the richest patrons, not by the club pro, even though the pro could definitely put them to better use. Golf is a pastime played for status and enjoyment, and no one is overly concerned about the outcome of any given game. But for events where a specific outcome matters, better tools should go to those who can use them better. Better soldiers should get better weapons, better musicians should get better instruments, better sculptors should get better stone, better leaders should get better positions… To do otherwise is wasteful.

Tell me briefly, what you call tools and what you call things in life?

@Mass: A tool is anything that's value lies mainly in its ability to produce an effect (i.e., the value of the thing in itself is negligible). Note that this includes organizations, institutions, factories, or other social structures organized for specific goals.  A thing is something with intrinsic value. It's a contextual distinction. Apple pie has a certain nutritional value and could thus be viewed as a tool (a dietary supplement), but generally we see it as a thing to be consumed for pleasure.

We deserve what we earn, as we earn it and show that we can apply it well. If we have not earned it yet, we do not deserve it yet, though we may get it in anticipation thereof. In addition, simply by being human members of a society, I would argue that we deserve what the society and its code of ethics promise us. ("Life, liberty, and the fursuit of happiness"?)
I don't play flute, but I do have a musical instrument that is of better quality then I can currently do justice to. I don't claim to deserve it, I merely could afford it and hope to eventually deserve it.
I would not say that the best things should only or immediately go to the best in the field. Among other things, it is sometimes impossible to identify the best in the field, or the best things, or the field itself. Best is not a single axis, as the boxer paradox demonstrates. (A beats B by combining skill and speed, B beats C by combining speed and strength, C beats A by combining strength and skill. Nobody is overall best, just different.)
Also, sometimes one becomes the best by overcoming challenges, potentially including learning how to work with a less forgiving instrument.

"best things in life should only go to the best in that field" - It is too philosophical of a question.
We can successfully describe the best available materials, tools and processes existing and produced in our reality. How the quality and sophistication of these tools correlates to the "best things in life" is more complicated.
In consumer society, the rich can acquire the best quality, but are these 'things' good for their lives?
Our lives are a careful balance of pluses and minuses, gifts and losses. If you get something good and don't produce the expected result, you are likely to be punished with a loss or misfortune. So, for the subject of Christmas Gifts, as usual, be careful what you wish for.

In fact, Aristotle was not referring to material goods. What he really meant was in society, who deserves what? Who should have this position? Who should teach? Who should be led? It talks about the fair distribution of goods and services. The best political positions should go to those who best manage the affairs of the city, if we stick to the Aristotelian version of politics as the art of managing the affairs of the city. But that's philosophy in the end, we ask ourselves questions that we can't provide a definitive answer to.

The problem is that you cannot be too smart in life. It was historically and philosophically proven. As soon as you think that you know what is good, what is just, what is fair - you are very quickly proven wrong.

Too philosophical? For a philosophy Q&A site? Perhaps you meant to vague, or some other term.

Your comment above — cannot be too smart — is probably more important than the rest you've written. Agree with @CriglCragl that "too philosophical" makes little sense. Maybe you wantb"very" not  "too"

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: Do you know what categories of views there are on goodness, & justice & fairness? Do you know what key philosophers have argued for about them? You seem to take a stance that we can literally know nothing about those things, & yet you use those words & we know what you mean. How do you reconcile that? It seems like you have a problem with too precise or constrained a way of thinking about those words. Perhaps give examples of people being 'too smart', or of being 'proven wrong' about the way they understood those words

@CriglCragl - It is really common and universally accepted knowledge. Did you hear the expression "The road to hell is paved with good intentions"? Just a small illustration: French revolutionaries Maximilien Robespierre, Georges Danton
